# Void function that returns average,max,min,and takes as parameter an array and the number of inputs

Tags: c, void

So I'm trying to create a program that returns the average ,min and max from a void function. I can't really see what is wrong with the code and I'm hoping someone can help.The compiler doesn't find any error or warning but when i run the program i get "Process exited with return value 3221225477".
The problem seems to be in the function i created.
Thanks in advance.

```
    void emporeuma(double array[], int plithos, double* avg, double* max, 
    double* min, int* plit)
    {
    int j;
    double sum;
    avg=0;
    sum=0;
   *plit=plithos;
    for(j=0;j<plithos-1;j++){

     sum=sum + array[j];
        }
    *avg=sum/plithos;
     *min=array[0];
     *max=array[0];
     for(j=1;j<plithos-1;j++)
     {
       if (array[j]>*max)
        {
          array[j]=*max;
           }

       if (array[j]<*min)
        {
        array[j]=*min;
         }

         }
```

Comment: Please learn to indent the code in a proper way

Comment: How is this function called?  Please include that in the question.

Comment: I have named the function emporeuma.

Comment: @ΔέσποιναΘωμαΐδη Not the name of the function, the call to invoke this function with all necessary variables.  Your question should be in the form of a [mcve] that others can compile and run to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Use English names for your variables, so that non Greek speakers can understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

```
    avg=0;
    ...
    *avg=sum/plithos;
```

crashes your program. You probably want to write `*avg = 0`.

Answer (score 0):

The loop is one too short, and the max and min tracking is back-to-front. Here is a suggested edit of that part:

```
for(j = 1; j < plithos; j++) {    // extend to the last element
    if (array[j] > *max) {
        *max = array[j];          // update the max
    }
    if (array[j] < *min) {
        *min = array[j];          // update the min
    }
    sum += array[j];              // ready to calculate avg
}
avg = sum / plithos;              // average
```